# Can I estimate this integral like that?

Tags: calculus, integration, estimation

I have the following integral $ \int_{2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{x^{3}-1}} d x $ and I should solve it without calculate it directly.
So if I find two function which is smaller and bigger than $ \int_{2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{x^{3}-1}} d x $ and those converges, then my integral has to converge too.

So i would like to choose $ 0 \le  \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{x^{3}-1}} d x \geq   \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{x^{5}}} $ is this possible ?

Comment: This integral diverges as $\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{x^3-1}} \ge \frac{1}{x}$ on $[2, \infty)$.

Comment: Yes, this is possible and both your lower bounds are correct.  You have not shown an upper bound, but if you find a function larger than your integrand it will provide an upper bound.  As your integral diverges, any upper bound will diverge, too

Answer (score 5):

The improper integral
$$\int_2^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{x^3-1}} dx$$
diverges. We find that
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{x^3-1}} > \frac{1}{x}$$
for all $x \in [2,\infty)$, and because $\int_2^{\infty}\frac{1}{x}dx$ diverges, we can conclude by the direct comparison test that the orginal improper integral is also divergent.

Answer (score 2):

As others have pointed out this integrals is divergent. It would be
nice to know this *a priori* so that we have some idea on how to go
about constructing a proof of the fact. Here is a way to think about
doing so.

#### Scratch work/Reasoning/hand-waving/ :).

Integrals whose limits of integration involve $\pm \infty$ are called
improper integrals of `type I`. Whether such an integrals diverges or
converges depends on what happens to the `tail` of the function. In
our case we want to think about what happens to
$\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{x^3-1}}$ when $x$ is very large. Indeed when $x$ is
very large (positive) $x^3 -1 \approx x^3$. Therefore

\begin{align}
 \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{x^3 -1}} \approx \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{x^3}} = \frac{1}{x}
\end{align}

for very large $x$.

Now instead of thinking about the *difficult* function we think of
this simplified version. What do we know about

\begin{align}
\int_2^\infty \frac{1}{x}
\end{align}

We know from our knowledge about $p$- integrals that it diverges. So
we expect our original integral to diverge as well. It is now time
to make this more precise. But now that I know what I would *like*
to show I can go about constructing the appropriate inequality.

To be able to invoke the comparison theorem for improper integrals
I would like
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{x} \stackrel{?}{\leq} \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{x^3 -1}} \;\;,
\text{for}\; x \geq 2.
\end{align}

Let's reverse engineer this and see if it holds water. Well,

\begin{align}
& \frac{1}{x} {\leq} \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{x^3 -1}} \\
& \iff \sqrt[3]{x^3 -1} \leq x, \quad \text{cross multiplying} \\
& \iff x^3 - 1 \leq x^3, \quad \text{taking cubes of both sides} \\
& \iff x^3 \leq x^3 + 1
\end{align}
The last inequality is certainly true for $x \geq 2$. We are now in a
position to write a proper mathematical argument to show what we intended.

---

### Proof

We have,
$$
\frac{1}{x} \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{x^3 -1}},
$$
for $x \geq 2$. We also know that $\displaystyle \int_2^\infty
                                   \frac{1}{x} \; dx$
is divergent. By the comparison theorem for improper integrals
we can now conclude that

$$
\int_2^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{x^3 -1}}\;dx,
$$
also diverges.

---

The type of `asymptotic` reasoning we did in our scratch work is
helpful in giving us some hints as to how we should proceed with
our reasoning. i.e., Are we trying to prove `convergence` or
`divergence`? (and consequently exactly which *direction* should our
inequalities be etc).

To see if you understood see if you can answer the following:

---

### Exercise

Determine if 
$$
\int_2^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^5 + x^3 + x^2 + 1}}\; dx
$$

is convergent or divergent. Justify your answer.

Comment: OK lets try:

We have, $0 \leq  \frac { 1 }{ \sqrt { x^{ 5 }+x^{ 3 }+x^{ 2 }+1 }  } \leq \frac { 1 }{ \sqrt { x^{ 5 } }  }  $ for $x \geq 2$.
We also know that $\underset { b\to \infty -\quad  }{ lim } \int _{ 2 }^{ b }{ \frac { 1 }{ \sqrt { x^{ 5 } }  } dx } =\quad \underset { b\to \infty -\quad  }{ lim } (-\frac { 2 }{ 3\sqrt { { b }^{ 3 } }  } )+\frac { 2 }{ 3\sqrt { { 2 }^{ 3 } }  } \quad =\quad \frac { 2 }{ 3\sqrt { { 2 }^{ 3 } }  } $ converges.
With the upper comparison test we know that $\int_2^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^5 + x^3 + x^2 + 1}}\; dx$ also converges. Could that be right?

Comment: Thanks btw for your very good answer

Comment: Yes, except you probably meant $b \to \infty$